# Bitcoin Testnet is not working

Tags: testnet

I am new to Bitcoin Development Environment. Trying to setup testnet environment with the help [this blog post](http://suffix.be/blog/getting-started-bitcoin-testnet).

```
Bitcoin Folder
~/.bitcoin $ ls
bitcoin.conf  chainstate  db.log     peers.dat
blocks        database    debug.log  wallet.dat
```

**bitcoin.conf**

```
telnet=1
server=1
rpcuser=userme
rpcpassword=mypassword
rpctimeout=30
rpcport=8332
```

**Running Bitcoin**

```
~/.bitcoin $ bitcoin-qt
"sni-qt/2440" WARN  16:37:44.104 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE
```

Comment: That there looks likes a warning. No real programmer actually cares about those. Are you sure the program is not running fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you choosing testnet network?
In `bitcoin.conf` should it really be `telnet=1`?
Maybe you meant `testnet=1`?

Comment: You are right. I guess the typo was the problem.